# Implementing GSL synchronized_value

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, thread-safety, concurrency

Core Guidelines mention a type `synchronized_value<T>`, which supposedly pairs `std::mutex` with the internal value. I couldn't find any implementation both in *GSL-Lite* and *MS GSL* libraries.
The SV class stores `T value` coupled with `std::mutex`. It implements pointer and dereference operators which create a temporary object of `xlock` which locks the mutex while alive.

Example usage is:

```
synchronized_value<Dummy> svDummy{}; // when Dummy is default-constructable
Foo(*svDummy);
```

When `Foo()` is called, a temporary `xlock` locks the mutex and keeps it until the function returns.

I implemented my class and want to have it reviewed.

I decided to delete move constructors of `xlock`, because it stores a reference and I don't want to deal with invalid state. Moreover I see no reason for such functionality.

To check the implementation I have written 3 tests: 2 control with `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` that explicitly lock a separate mutex. And 1 with `synchronized_value`. All the tests are passing.

Here is a link to my [repository](https://github.com/ElDesalmado/synchronized_value) with the library and tests (CTest).

```
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ...>
using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename Tuple, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_aggregate_constructable_ : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
struct is_aggregate_constructable_<T,
        std::tuple<Args...>,
        void_t<decltype(T{Args()...})>> : std::true_type
{
};

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
struct is_aggregate_constructable :
        is_aggregate_constructable_<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
};

// TODO: add timer?
template<typename T, typename Mutex = std::mutex>
class xlock
{
public:
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<T>::value, const T, T>;
    using mutex_type = Mutex;

    xlock(value_type &refValue, Mutex &mutex)
            : refValue_(refValue),
              uniqueLock_(mutex)
    {}

    xlock(const xlock &other) = delete;

    xlock(xlock &&other) = delete;

    xlock &operator=(const xlock &other) = delete;

    xlock &operator=(xlock &&other) = delete;

    value_type *operator->()
    { return &refValue_; }

    const value_type *operator->() const
    { return &refValue_; }

    value_type &operator*()
    { return refValue_; }

    const value_type &operator*() const
    { return refValue_; }

    operator value_type &()
    { return refValue_; }

    operator const value_type &() const
    { return refValue_; }

    ~xlock()
    {

    }

private:
    value_type &refValue_;
    std::unique_lock<mutex_type> uniqueLock_;
};

template<typename T, typename Mutex = std::mutex>
class synchronized_value
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using mutex_type = Mutex;
    using xlock_t = xlock<value_type, mutex_type>;
    using cxlock_t = xlock<const value_type, mutex_type>;

    template<typename =
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>>
    synchronized_value()
    {};

    explicit synchronized_value(T value)
            : value_(std::forward<T>(value))
    {}
    synchronized_value(const synchronized_value &) = delete;
    synchronized_value &operator=(const synchronized_value &) = delete;

    synchronized_value(synchronized_value &&other) = delete;
    synchronized_value &operator=(synchronized_value &&other) = delete;

    xlock_t operator*()
    { return {value_, mutex_}; }

    cxlock_t operator*() const
    { return {value_, mutex_}; }

    xlock_t operator->()
    { return {value_, mutex_}; }

    cxlock_t operator->() const
    { return {value_, mutex_}; }

    value_type &value()
    { return value_; }

    const value_type& value() const
    { return value_; }

private:
    value_type value_;
    mutable mutex_type mutex_;
};
```

Testing functions:

```
// run_check.h

#pragma once

#include "synchronized_value/synchronized_value.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct Dummy
{
    int64_t id;
    bool b;
};

struct Wrapped
{
    synchronized_value<Dummy>& sv;
};

// false if check is successful
bool run_check(Dummy& d, int64_t assign, size_t intervals)
{
    d.id = assign;

    // std::cout << "run_check " << assign << " thread: " <<
       //       std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    for (size_t i = 0; i != intervals; ++i)
        ++d.id;
    // std::cout << "end_check " << assign << " thread: " <<
       //       std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n' << std::endl;

    return bool(d.id - assign - intervals);
}

bool run_check_w(Wrapped& w, int64_t assign, size_t intervals)
{
    return run_check(*w.sv, assign, intervals);
}

template <typename Guard>
bool check_mutex(Dummy& d, std::mutex& mutex, uint64_t assign, size_t intervals)
{
    Guard guard{mutex};
    d.id = assign;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != intervals; ++i)
        ++d.id;

    return bool(d.id - assign - intervals);
}
```

Testing unit:

```
#include "run_check.h"

#include <future>
#include <random>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool is_same_v = std::is_same<T1, T2>::value;


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    size_t intervals = 10000;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        try
        {
            intervals = std::stoll(argv[1]);
        }
        catch (const std::invalid_argument &)
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid argument for intervals: using " << intervals <<
                      " intervals fot test" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    static_assert(is_aggregate_constructable<Dummy, uint64_t, bool>(), "Invalid result");
    static_assert(is_aggregate_constructable<Dummy, int, bool>(), "Invalid result");
    static_assert(is_aggregate_constructable<Dummy, int, int>(), "Invalid result");
    static_assert(!is_aggregate_constructable<Dummy, double, int>(), "Invalid result");

    static_assert(is_same_v<typename xlock<Dummy>::value_type,
            Dummy>, "Invalid result");
    static_assert(is_same_v<typename xlock<const Dummy>::value_type,
            const Dummy>, "Invalid result");

    std::mutex mutex;
    Dummy d{1};
    {
        xlock<Dummy> xlock1{d, mutex};
        xlock1->id;
        Dummy dummy = *xlock1;
        Dummy& refDummy = *xlock1;
        const Dummy& crefDummy = *xlock1;
    }
    {
        xlock<const Dummy> xlock_const{d, mutex};
        xlock_const->id;

        Dummy dummy = *xlock_const;
        // Dummy& refDummy = *xlock_const;
        const Dummy& crefDummy = *xlock_const;
    }
    {
        const xlock<const Dummy> xlock_const{d, mutex};
        xlock_const->id;
    }
    {
        synchronized_value<Dummy> synchValue{d};
        synchValue->id;
        Dummy dummy = *synchValue;
        Dummy& refDummy = *synchValue;
        const Dummy& crefDummy = *synchValue;
    }
    {
        const synchronized_value<Dummy> synchValueConst2{d};
        synchValueConst2->id;
        Dummy dummy = *synchValueConst2;
        // Dummy& refDummy = *synchValueConst2;
        const Dummy& crefDummy = *synchValueConst2;
    }

    synchronized_value<Dummy> dummy{{16}};

    bool first_check = run_check(*dummy, 42, 1000);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int64_t> dist(-69800, 385697);

    std::vector<Wrapped> input(1000, {dummy});
    std::vector<std::future<bool>> results;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
    {
        results.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                &run_check_w,
                std::ref(input[i]),
                dist(rng),
                intervals));
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
        result += (int)results[i].get();

    return result;
}
```

Control tests you can find at my repo.

How it can be improved? What may have I missed?

---

I updated this question. I found out that initial test was incorrect, but I have fixed it. Now everything works

Comment: You haven't clearly explained (nor linked to an explanation of) what `synchronized_value<T>` is supposed to do, nor what `xlock` is supposed to do. You ask why your test harness "fails," but surely you could find that out by compiling it and seeing which line has the error, right? Or which of the tests misbehaves at run time? The whole point of testing is to find out _what_ goes wrong and _why_. If you don't know, then your tests aren't granular enough.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I thought saying that it pairs `std::mutex` to the value is enough. If not, later I will add this explanation. `xlock` is an object that locks the mutex while it is alive and is created when `synchronized_value` gets dereferenced. So when I pass `Dummy` to `run_check` by dereferencing synch value, I lock its mutex in a temporary `xlock` object. It should not be unlocked until function has returned and a destructor of `xlock` has been locked. Basically it is the same approach as locking mutex, but in this case it is stored within.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I can not *find out which line has error* since it is undetectable (on 10000 invocations there are only 10-100 fails). And happens **only** in **Debug** mode.

Comment: Ah, your `xlock` doesn't match anything in the [proposal P0290](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0290r2.html). What you're missing is the `apply` function that takes a callable and a pack of SVs, calls `std::lock` with all the SVs, calls the callable with the-values-of-all-the-SVs, and then unlocks all the SVs before returning. If your test fails only 1 in 1000 times, try running it 1000 times and then see which line has the failure. You might need to add some debugging printfs, or split the test program into smaller pieces.

Comment: @Quuxplusone this is completely different story. The proposal is for `std::apply` to be able to take SVs as arguments, my class is for locking on dereferencing. Though I have an idea that my test does something wrong.